# How to save offset id inside Zookeeper while consuming with Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am using Spark to consume data from Kafka.I am writing the program in Java. I want to be able to save the offset id in Zookeeper and be able to restart from the last consumed offset id. How do I save the offset id in Zookeeper?

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("name");
JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(2000));
Map<String,String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
kafkaParams.put("zookeeper.connect", "127.0.0.1");
kafkaParams.put("group.id", App.GROUP);
JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, EventLog> messages =
  KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, String.class, EventLog.class, StringDecoder.class, EventLogDecoder.class,
    kafkaParams, topicMap, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2());
```